# how to find the components of the vector $\vec{P_1P_2}$ where $P_1(3,5)$ and $P_2(2,8)$?

Tags: vector-spaces

I am doing in this way vector vector $\vec{P_1P_2} = (2 - 3,8 - 5)$ . or do i have to calculate the unit vector and then divided by the length of the $\vec{P_1P_2}$ vector ?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this is true, we get $\vec{P_1P_2}=(2-3,8-5)=(-1,3)$

Comment: thanks. what if i calculate the unit vector of this vector and then divided by the length of the vector ? is that the same component i will get ?